# Retrieving image from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the code below to upload and retrieve image from mysql database. Images are successfully uploaded and moved to a separate folder but image paths are not storing in the database so I am unable to retrieve images from the database. Please check where is the problem

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
              $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false){
              $target="images/".basename($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
              $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
              $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
              $uploadfilename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        /*
         * Insert image data into database
         */

       $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //Insert image content into database
          $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (image,created)   VALUES('$imgContent', '$dataTime')");
      //move uploaded file to the folder images//


      if($uploadfilename!=''){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$target)
          $query="INSERT INTO images SET imgepath='$uploadfilename' ";
        mysqli_query($query);
        if($query){

           { 
            echo "File uploaded  successfully.";
           }
        }else{
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
    }
    }
   }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.Below code is working now.i made a database table named "images" with colms "id","name"(where i saved the image's name) and "url"

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $host = "...";
    $db_name = "....";
    $username = "....";
    $password = ".....";
    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
    $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filetmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $target="uploaded/".$filename;
    $image_url="http://holo-com.stackstaging.com/uploaded".$filename;
    $sql="INSERT INTO images (name,image_url) VALUES  ('$filename','$image_url')";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$target))
    {   echo "Image uploaded";  }
}
else
{   echo "Failed to upload";    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the folder path of the image or your `$target` variable instead of `$imgContent`.

```
"INSERT into images (image,created) VALUES('$target', '$dataTime')"
```

Also this is prone to SQL injections, use prepared statements:

```
// connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT into images (image,created) VALUES(?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $target, $dataTime);

//execute
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the image name in the Database and upload the image in the server while retrieving you can use the folder name followed by the image name. For example, if the folder name where the image is uploaded is upload

```html
<img src="uploads/<?= $v1['image']?>" alt="product">
```

Comment: FYI `<?=` will only work when short tags are enabled for php, better use `<?php echo $v1['image'] ;?>`